# react Suspense (or equivalent) while Stripe loads iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, lazy-loading, user-experience

I have an issue where Stripe's React `PaymentElement` loads *very slowly* for most of my users (I can't replicate this behavior, but PageSpeed hates it, and AWS CloudWatch RUM is reporting terrible user page load and time-to-interactive numbers).

I thought I would resolve it by lazy loading the Stripe `PaymentElement`. What I have now is:

```
// Lazy-load PaymentElement even though not default export
const PaymentElement = React.lazy(() =>
  import('@stripe/react-stripe-js').then(module => {
    return { default: module.PaymentElement };
  })

const CheckoutForm = () => {
 // ...
 return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Suspense fallback={<StripePlaceholder />}>
          <PaymentElement />
        </Suspense>
    </form>
  );
};
```

The problem I'm having is my `<StripePlaceholder />` fallback renders for a bit, but then disappears, and even on a fast connection on a laptop, there's still a substantial visual delay between the time it goes away, which I guess means the `<PaymentElement />` has "rendered", and the time the form actually appears — which delay I believe is the difference between the component rendering and the iframe loading.

Is there some way for me to get the placeholder to stay in place while the iframe is loading? I'm not wed to the lazy/Suspense method — I just want some placeholder in place for the apparent 5-10 seconds it takes for some of my users to actually load the form.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the option ["loader"](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create#stripe_elements-options-loader). Set it to `always`.

> Display skeleton loader UI while waiting for Elements to be fully loaded, after they are mounted. Default is 'auto' (Stripe determines if a loader UI should be shown).